# Can a quantifier bind a name in FOL formulas

Tags: logic

For example, if I have
∀a(∀x∃z(P(m) & Q(x,z,a)) || R(a,b)) (|| means OR), can I say it is a well formed formula in FOL.

If I remove the ∀a at the beginning, can I now claim it is a well formed formula (wff)?

How about, if it is just Q(a,b,c,x,y,z), can I say this is a wff?

Comment: Regardless of FOL, names are supposed to be labels for unique objects, so what would quantifying over them even mean? It effectively turns them into variables.

Comment: I thought so too which is why I initially said it is not a well formed formula but it felt like the system was gaslighting me. Turned out they mistakenly put one wrong answer as a correct but that has been cleared up now.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You cannot bind names in basic FOL so yes, if you remove the for all a, it becomes valid. The Q one is also valid.

Comment: The proper term you are looking for is "well-formed formula" or wff for short. It means a formula that obeys the syntactic and grammatical rules of the language. "Valid formula" means something else: a formula that is true in all interpretations.

Comment: @Bumble Yeah, I changed the question to reflect this but to be fair, this is the first time I am hearing it be called a wff.